# Capybara tests randomly fail when browser window is not visible or focused?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rspec, capybara

I'm using Capybara (on MacOS via rspec and rails, selenium-webdriver 2.51.0, chrome driver helper 1.0.0, ChromeDriver 2.25.426935) and my specs take about 5 minutes to run.

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, 
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: {
      "chromeOptions" => {
        "args" => %w{ window-size=1440,768 } 
      }
    }
  )
end
```

I have struggled a lot to get reliable results from these specs, even though they all pass on their own. I have come to discover through trial and error that if the Capybara browser window is visible for the whole time the specs are running, then they will all pass. But if it's not, it's a crap shoot (unpredictable).

Naturally I want to do other things (continue working) while the specs are running and not stare at the spec window.

So my questions are:

- Is my understanding correct that the Capybara window being visible somehow involved in random test failures?
- Is this something that can be changed either in Capybara, Rspec, or MacOS?
- What are my options for being able to continue working while my specs are running?

Thanks folks,
Ben

Comment: What driver/browser are you using - include versions

Comment: added chromedriver 1.0.0 to the post

Comment: Does that mean you're using selenium with chrome, if so what version of selenium-webdriver are you using?  - the latest version of the chromedriver executable is 2.27.xxx, I am somewhat shocked that 1.0.0 would work with any modern version of chrome.

Comment: selenium-webdriver (2.51.0) also updated

Comment: If you are using that with chrome -- update to selenium-webdriver 3.0.7 and make sure you're using chromedriver 2.27 , the versions you are using are painfully old

Comment: I don't think the chromedriver-helper I mention is the same as chromedriver https://rubygems.org/gems/chromedriver-helper/versions/1.0.0

Comment: @ThomasWalpole do you think this update will fix the issue I mention?

Comment: hmm.. chromedriver-helper hasn't been updated since July-2015. Check what version of the chromedriver binary that is installing for you and make sure you're running the latest version of the binary.  Yes I think it will fix the issue.

Comment: You might also want to change from chromedriver-helper to the webdrivers gem (https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers) which appears to be the modern version of it.

Comment: ChromeDriver 2.25.426935 is what seems to be installed with the helper

Comment: You need to keep those up to date, especially since chrome auto-updates

Comment: well I guess I would have to stop using this gem, or push a PR

Comment: or potentially just run `chromedriver-update`

Comment: haha, that was easy! Well we'll see if it helps, and if so I'll have you make a proper answer and give you some points!